# Ionic Network Performance Analysis - Duplicate Calls

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

I have an ionic 3 application and I am doing some performance testing for my queries. I noticed that for every api call I am seeing duplicates calls; One initiated from **'polyfill.js'** and one from **'other'**. Is this something normal?  I put the network mode on '2g' and I noticed it needed 2 seconds to finish the call from the polyfill then it actually the started the main call.

```
Name            Status  Type  Initiator                 Size     Time      
GetCustomers    200     xhr   polyfills.js?v=1.1.1.3:3  262 B   2.06 s
GetLocations    200     xhr   polyfills.js?v=1.1.1.3:3  262 B   2.03 s

GetCustomers    200     xhr   Other                     380 B   2.52 s
GetLocations    200     xhr   Other                     310 B   2.22 s
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are running into [this](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12684) issue. 
 Basically when directly loading a tabs-page in ionic (through loading a nested link that loads a tab page directly, or reloading a tabs page for example), the ionic lifecylce components are loaded twice. This is a known bug in ionic that unfortunately has not been fixed yet. There are some workarounds that are explained in the issue thread that I linked above.

I ran into this issue when executing my API calls in ionic lifecycle events like
`ionViewDidLoad` or `ionViewWillEnter`

Comment: No when I debug backend it is actually entering only once. Also the Size is always '262B' constant for the first one. I just want to understand whats that.